# net view \\share works but explorer.exe entering \\share gives "not accessible" error?

Tags: windows-explorer, network-shares, shared-folders, smb, net-use

This is driving me crazy.

I have a file share I'm accessing from Windows 8.1 (call it "svrname").

- If I type `net view \\svrname` in cmd.exe, it succeeds and gives a list of shares.
- if I type `\\svrname` into explorer.exe I get the well-known error `"\\svrname is not accessible. You may not have permission"`
- if I type `\\10.x.x.x` (IP of \svrname) into Explorer.exe, it asks for a user+password and works. The entry shows up in "Credential Manager".
- On the basis that this shows browsing basically works and lookup's an issue, I try to type the host or FQDN of `svrname` identically into Credential Manager, and otherwise enter the identical name+pw.  I indeed get the error I got above. This suggests it's a lookup issue, but then ------- when I ping `svrname` by either host or FQDN, or use nslookup, it finds the IP without trouble, which suggests it isn't.

I've tried troubleshooting with wireshark but can't figure what I need to look for.

**Updates** - @ddbug, Samba 4.6. Samba logs show (and wireshark confirms) that all packets are arriving. The nmbd/smbd logs (and client SMB packet contents in Wireshark) are a bit strange and make no sense to me at all, I can't figure what the underlying issue is that they're trying to tell me. But that would be a fair bit of data.

Two possible issues I'm seeing are that the server is reporting at times that it can't find its own workgroup<1b>, but I can't tell if that's a genuine error or not (could be either?), and the client seems to not be passing credentials for domain/user in some cases even though it's clearly got them (in multiple formats and entries), and I can't figure why not.

**update 2** - there's no LDAP, AD or other auth, its samba or nothing. There's a local domain (call it `thislan.xyz`) and dhcp+dns, but no directory service. The user access itself (including password) is fine, because I can browse 100% by IP, with null and guest disabled.

part of what I'm seeing is that the relevant initial SMB authentication requests by client to server don't always seem to include a user or domain, they're empty fields. I can't understand that at all, and that seems a big part of it. How is it possible for them to be empty? Where do they get their data from (that they should contain for these fields)  to trace it? I can't find anywhere missing this data that hasn't had it correctly entered as they should be.

Comment: What kind of a server it is? Some non-Windows samba thing?

Comment: I believe that netview just reads the browselist for the server. samba/SMB servers exchange lists of shares, and browser operations run as System, so there is no guarentee of parity between the two.

Comment: @ddbug - updated OP

Comment: @FrankThomas - can you elaborate? I don't quite get the detail of what you are saying, although it sounds relevant.

Comment: I'm saying that to enumerate shares in Explorer, your users access is evaluated, but that for net view, it is not. if you are in a workgroup scenario, have you run `smbpasswd` for your user on the samba server?

Comment: If you see auth errors, maybe the server is configured to use ldap or smth. else on another server which is not reachable.

Comment: @ddbug, frankthomas - Updated x 2